# Eclipse RCP - active dialog from command handler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I've registered a key binding in the `org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow` context.
I've then associated a command handler

```
public class QuickActionsHandler extends AbstractHandler {
  @Override
  public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
     ...
```

Now, how do I get the active Dialog view part from the `ExecutionEvent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogs are not view parts - they are generally just windows extending `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog`

Probably the best you can do is get the currently active Shell:

```
Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event);
```